# CSS inline-block won't show up in a browser as link

Tags: html, css

**I'm trying to style my link with black background, using the code below:**

```
a#link-1: link{
    background: black;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

**However; it won't show up on the browser!**

Please, check it out. [This is the entire code](https://jsfiddle.net/ehc5skbv/1/)

Comment: Remove the space in `a#link-1: link` or just get rid of the `:` and `link` altogether

Comment: Thank you, 
I removed the spacing it solved my problem. I have also did the other and removed : and link all together and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that the effect you want ?

https://jsfiddle.net/ehc5skbv/2/

```css
a#link-1 {
    background: #333;
    padding: 10px;
       
}
```

Comment: Remove the space in a#link-1: link or just get rid of the : and link altogether